# Corona/json Using json to save highscores

Tags: json, coronasdk

I am trying to create a game where the high score is saved using json. But I am having troubles. A friend of mine helped me set up the json. And it should be saving the high score if they have never played before or if they have beaten their high score, and printing out what it is doing to the console. But it doesn't seem to be saving the score as it keeps returning nil and displaying the current score. The code for this section is below. Thanks in advance.

```
local json = require("json")

function saveTable(t, filename)
   local path = system.pathForFile( filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)    
   local file = io.open(path, "w")
   if file then 
       local contents = json.encode(t)  
       file:write( contents )   
       io.close( file ) 
       return true  
   else 
       return false
   end  
   end  
function loadTable(filename)
   local path = system.pathForFile( filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)
   local contents = ""
   local myTable = {}
   local file = io.open( path, "r" )
   if file then 
        local contents = file:read( "*a" )
        myTable = json.decode(contents);
        io.close( file )
   return myTable 
   end  
   return nil   
end

        myGameSettings = {}
        highscore = myGameSettings.highScore
        if(highscore == nil)then
        highscore = score
        myGameSettings.highScore = highscore
        print("score was nil")
        end
        if(highscore < score)then
        highscore = score
        myGameSettings.highScore = highscore
        print ("highscore beaten")
        end
        displayHighScoreNumber = display.newText("Your score: ", 160, 150,        
                    native.systemFontBold, 40 )
        displayHighScoreNumber.text = highscore
        displayingHighScore = 1;

        myGameSettings = loadTable("mygamesettings.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually have some of my own JSON saving code that you can use. Here is an example that you can use for OS Time.  To view the txt file, go to your Corona Sandbox (accessible via the Corona Simulator).

```
local json = require("json")
time = os.time() --Get OS Time 
print (time)
local gameState = {
    time,
}
function Load( pathname ) --load a table from a file, this is just one way to do saves
    local data = nil
    local path = system.pathForFile( pathname..".txt", system.DocumentsDirectory  ) --get the file path
    local fileHandle = io.open( path, "r" ) -- open the file
    if fileHandle then -- if opening the file worked, read the file.
        data = json.decode( fileHandle:read( "*a" ) ) -- decode the JSON into a lua table
        io.close( fileHandle ) -- close the opened file
    end 
    return data -- return the loaded table
end

function Save( data, pathname ) -- save a table to a file
    local success = false 
    local path = system.pathForFile( pathname..".txt", system.DocumentsDirectory  ) -- get the file path
    local fileHandle = io.open( path, "w" ) -- open the file 
    if fileHandle then -- if it worked write the file
        fileHandle:write( json.encode( data ) ) -- encode the table into JSON, then write it to file
        io.close( fileHandle ) -- close the file
        success = true
    end
    return success --return true if it worked, false otherwise
end

Save( gameState, "time4" ) --Game state is the table of values, time 4 is the file name
local gameState = Load( "time4" )
--Now if you print out gamestate, it should print the time.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    myGameSettings = {}
    myGameSettings = loadTable("mygamesettings.json")

    highscore = myGameSettings.highScore
    if(highscore == nil)then
        highscore = score
        myGameSettings.highScore = highscore
        print("score was nil")
    end
    if(highscore < score)then
        highscore = score
        myGameSettings.highScore = highscore
        print ("highscore beaten")
    end
    displayHighScoreNumber = display.newText("Your score: ", 160, 150,        
                native.systemFontBold, 40 )
    displayHighScoreNumber.text = highscore
    displayingHighScore = 1;
```

You were creating an empty table, which is always going to have a highScore that is nil.  Try loading the table in first.  Don't forget to save the table after updating it.